# Story of the "marching" version of the song Kel Adon

Tags: sources-mekorot, music, shabbat-songs, chassidic-rebbe, story-identification

I recall once hearing that a chassidic rebbe composed a marching-style tune for the Shabbat piyut Kel Adon. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrBU1IDuKbs) was the closest thing I could find to the tune.  I found very few [references](http://www.mishpacha.com/Browse/Article/9957/Endnote-Songs-from-the-Rebbes-Court) to it  online. From what I recall of the story a Rebbe was performing some sort of forced labor in the concentration camps, he passed out and when he came to he said that the angels in heaven had taught him this song. I would like to know what the story of the origin of the tune is.

Comment: Is it [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORbCNAUaLp4&ab_channel=%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A5-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93%D7%96%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90)?